# New to ruby, hard time understanding combined ruby/sql syntax (that is also hard to google)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would appreciate some pointers to how to interpret some probably trivial syntax in an sql statement within a ruby method

Basically, the function is like

```
def foo(param)
  connection.execute(<<-SQL ... WHERE tablename.fieldname <@ '#{param.somefield}')
  other stuff...
end
```

I am assuming the '#{param.somefield}' just puts in the value from param's "somefield" field in the raw sql, but I can't figure out what the "<@" means.  It seems that "<" can be a string comparison operator in SQL, but what is "@" doing?

thanks!

Comment: did you try `Model.where('fieldname <@ ?', param.somefield)` syntax?

Comment: thanks - not running this yet - first trying to understand what that "@" means - it might be some sort of (sql) shorthand for "ends with", but I haven't seen any docs on that - this is for postgres

Comment: Oh! My bad, I didn't read it through properly. I though you want the ruby based syntax to fire this query. :)

Comment: no prob - I had confused the issue by bringing ruby into the mix - it's apparently just a postgres-specific thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<@` has nothing to do with Ruby. It's a SQL operator that means `range is contained by`, used for range type in postgresql.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

Comment: thank you so much - I was getting no hits with a search for that symbol with however I was trying it and it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

`<@` is a PostgreSQL function on arrays or ranges that queries "is contained by".

Example:

```
ARRAY[2,7] <@ ARRAY[1,7,4,2,6] #=> t
```

You might want to read:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

It is worth noting that is works only on PostgreSQL databases and would raise an error on MySQL or SQLite